# PyTorch - How to process model input in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch

Consider the following simple neural net:

```
class CustomNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomNN, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        sleep(1)
        return x
```

I am wondering if we can call `forward()` in parallel. Following the [official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/torch-script-parallelism.html), I thought that the following code would work:

```
x = torch.rand(10, 5).cuda()
futures = [torch.jit.fork(model, x[i,:]) for i in range(10)]
results = [torch.jit.wait(fut) for fut in futures]
```

I expected this to run in about 1 second, but it still sleeps for the full 10 seconds. Is there any way to call the model in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in python, unfortunately, as per [torch.jit.fork](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.fork.html)
To serve TorchScript modules you need to make a C++ application with a proper thread pool – [see here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html#)

Besides, your code does not include (or you do not show it) the conversion.
You have to wrap the Module with `torch.jit.script` for it to be scripted (or traced) into ScriptModule

```
traced_NN = torch.jit.script(CustomNN())
```

Even still, it won't work, as only pytorch functions (and not even fully), python builtins, and `math` module is supported in TorchScript [(see here)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#python-functions-and-modules)